# Dimmer switch wiring question

Tags: electrical

[image][image]I’ve got a short in an old Lutron rotary dimmer.  It looks like this wired in. I don’t understand the wiring. The lines from the box that connect to the two red wires of the dimmer test hot.  So the black one must feed to the light?  What is the second (red) wire which is also hot ?  A traveler?  My new dimmer only has two black wires and a green ground wire. Do I connect red wire #2 to  the black wire on new dimmer which feeds the light?

Comment: Is there another lightswitch somewhere for the light this dimmer controls?

Comment: No there is not.  There is another dimmer in the same box that operates a different light, but neither one is a three way.

Comment: Can you provide us a with a clear photo looking into the back of the box in question please?

Comment: Guess what.  I just discovered that this was indeed wired as a three way switch but the other intended switch wasn’t completed.  I believe it is inoperable.  Also the neighboring three way switch doesn’t work properly.  It’s other switch must be in the on position for the light to turn on and for the dimmer to work at all.  I’m getting an electrician to fix it all since it seems wired incorrectly or at least with wrong switches on the “other” end from the dimmers.  Thanks!